# Can a 3rd party view previous changes / revisions in an excel workbook i have sent them?

Tags: excel, revision

I've got an excel workbook I'm editing (updating data, formulas, delete sheets etc) prior to being sent on to a 3rd party.

I worried about them being able to see the edits that I've made, is that possible? I've got track changes turned off. Would it still be possible for them to see the revision history or any other previous edited data such as deleted sheets in the workbook?

The excel file will be sent as an email attachment.

I'm editing in Excel for Mac 2011.

Comment: this question is probably better suited for SUPERUSERS stack exchange